# Unexpected end of file exception in CURL but POSTMAN and SOAP UI work fine

Tags: java, php, curl, soap, postman

I'm trying to communicate with a SOAP server over a proxy server in a PHP App.
All of the requests seem to be fine in the PHP App.One of the requests return me the following exception.If I test the same request in soapui and postman it seems to be ok.

I used the "Generate Code Snippets" function of POSTMAN to create the CURL request in PHP.I ended up with the following code.

```
 $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "********",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ws=\"http://ws.s5.mediasat.de/\"> "
        . "<soapenv:Header> <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\" soapenv:mustUnderstand=\"1\"> "
        . "<wsse:UsernameToken> <wsse:Username>******</wsse:Username> <wsse:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText\">********</wsse:Password> </wsse:UsernameToken> </wsse:Security> </soapenv:Header> "
        . "<soapenv:Body> <ws:putCall> <transaction>createIncident</transaction> <transactionID /> "
        . "<transactionSender>Submit Request</transactionSender> <caseDataModel> <senderId>19</senderId> "
        . "<ticketNumberSender>1234</ticketNumberSender> <ticketNumber /> <ticketTypeId>106</ticketTypeId> "
        . "<createTypeId>701</createTypeId> <title>Issue with priority (B001APP05M)</title> <description /> "
        . "<serviceId>I002S5001P</serviceId> <categoryId>128</categoryId> <serviceRecipientId>18176</serviceRecipientId> "
        . "<serviceLocationSAPCode>V135</serviceLocationSAPCode> <priorityId>102</priorityId> <assignmentUserId>458</assignmentUserId> "
        . "<CIName /> <timestampStart /> <timestampEnd /> <informationText /> <solutionText /> <solutionCode /> <closureText /> "
        . "<closureCode /> <cancellationText /> <cancellationCode /> <errorText /> <errorCode /> <nameSenderText /> <statusSenderText /> "
        . "<timestampSender /> <attachmentFilename /> <attachmentData /> </caseDataModel> </ws:putCall> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope> ",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "accept-charset: utf-8",
            "accept-encoding: utf-8",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "connection: Keep-Alive",
            "content-type: text/xml",
            "soapaction: \"/IntS5/S5WS\""
        ),
    ));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
```

**EXCEPTION:**

```
Error sending request to server ******* from interface null Error=java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.expect100Continue(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.cep.httpclient.standard.HttpClient.doRequest(HttpClient.java:339)
    at com.tibco.cep.httpclient.kernel.BaseHttpClient.process(BaseHttpClient.java:188)
    at com.tibco.cep.httpclient.kernel.HttpWorker.run(HttpWorker.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas why the server does not like my request body?

Comment: Is the Java tag necessary here? If not, can you remove it?

Comment: since I get a JAVA Exception its necessary so that some java developers could help me? I don't know under which circumstances java servers return this error.

Comment: `Unexpected end of file from server` would imply that the remote server accepted and closed the connection without sending a response. Probably has something to do with the proxy server. I'm no expert on any of this though.

Comment: yes proxy server does not like my request and closes the connection without sending me a response.Probably it has something to do with the request body.